# how get minimum time?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, computer-science

[image]

Let's say that we have this tree, and I want to return the the min_time that I can get with a specififc budget. Example: 350, min_time = 45, 700 min_time = 20, 1000 min_time =10, if the budget is less than or greater than the exisitin prices just return -1. How could do this in O(h) runtime, I need ideas please.

```
double get_min(node * t, double budget){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the design of binary search tree (BST) to your benefit.

Given any node in a BST, all the values on the right are greater than that node and on the left are less than that node.

You can use the search functionality with a revised way to find the node that fits in your budget.

```
int largestValueLessThanN(Node* root, int N) 
{ 
    // Base cases 
    if (root == NULL) 
        return -1; 
    if (root->key == N) 
        return N; 
  
    // If root's value is smaller, try in right subtree
    else if (root->key < N) { 
        int k = largestValueLessThanN(root->right, N); 
        if (k == -1) 
            return root->key; 
        else
            return k; 
    } 
  
    // If root's key is greater, return value from left subtree. 
    else if (root->key > N)  
        return largestValueLessThanN(root->left, N);     
}
```

In your case, it seems you need to find the node with largest price that is less than the budget specified, then you add the min time from that node.

You didn't mention what shall happen if budget after finding the needed node is large enough to get you another node. You can subtract the price of found node from your budget and again perform the same operation to fetch you another node.